# How to copy folder in UNIX with different owners and permissions to preserve it all in target location?

Tags: unix

I need to copy folder from a to b.
The folder owned by user1 and have folders and files owned by both user1 and user2 inside of it in different locations.

I need to copy it and preserve the ownership and permissions (ownership more important).

I don't have root permissions, I can login with both users.

cp -a and copy -p didn't help, when I copy in any way it will get the ownership of which user I'm log in with.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: maybe use `find`'s condition `-user` to select files owned by a specific user.

Comment: Maybe try with `tar`?  See https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch10_13.htm for full details.

Comment: This question belongs on [unix.se], as it is not programming-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say under `a` there's some file `a/x/y` that does not belong to you, `user1`, but rather belongs to `user2`.

You are trying to create a copy of `a`, `b`, such that `b/x/y` belongs to `user2`. Meaning, you are trying to create a file on someone else's behalf, and that is a security problem.

The OS will prevent you from doing that if you don't have root permissions. As mentioned in the comments, [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) is the closest you can get - an archive that will remember the permissions such that when you do have permissions to create files on behalf of `user2`, it will remember what files they are.

If you're wondering why it's a security problem to create files on someone else's behalf, here's just 2 examples:

1. Admin sets per-user quotas. Every user gets N GB of disk space. `user1` recreates the file `a/x/y`, under different file names, `b/x/y1`, `b/x/y2`, ..., on behalf of `user2`, in a loop, until the quota for `user2` is exhausted. `user1`, who owns the directories `b` and `b/x` then runs `chmod go-rwx b/x` such that `user2` can't even access the directory `b/x` to delete these files. `user2` now can't write anything to disk.
2. `user1` writes a program like `su` that changes its UID to root and runs `/bin/bash`. it creates a copy of it on behalf of (i.e. owned by) the root user, with mode `r-s` (read, write, setuid), which means that the program will succeed in changing its UID to root. Root shell achieved.